# Python : calling __new__ method of superclass

Tags: python, inheritance, overriding, subclass

I have two python classes defined like follows :

```
class A(object) : 

    def __init__(self, param) : 
        print('A.__init__ called')
        self.param = param

    def __new__(cls, param) :
        print('A.__new__ called') 
        x = object.__new__(A)
        x._initialize()    # initialization code
        return x

class B(A) : 

    def __init__(self, different_param) : 
        print('B.__init__ called')

    def __new__(cls, different_param) : 
        print('B.__new__ called')
        # call __new__ of class A, passing "param" as parameter
        # and get initialized instance of class B
        # something like below
        b = object.__new__(B)
        param = cls.convert_param(different_param)
        return super(B, cls).__new__(b, param)    # I am expecting something
                                                  # similar to this

    @staticmethod
    def convert_param(param) : 
        return param
```

`class B` is a subclass of `class A`. The difference between the two classes is that the parameters passed to `class B` are in a different format as compared to those expected by `class A`. So, the `convert_param` method of `classB` is called to convert the parameters to be compatible with the `__new__` method of `class A`.

I am stuck at the part where I wish to call the `__new__` method of `class A` from the `__new__` method of `class B`, since there is a lot of initialisation that takes place in there, and then get back the initialised instance of `class B`.

I am having a difficult time figuring this out. Please help.

Comment: Static methods don't take an implicit first argument: `def convert_param(param): ...`

Comment: @chepner again, a mistake. I edited it. but that's not the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`convert_param` should either be a `staticmethod` or a `classmethod` and you don't want to be calling `object.__new__` from `B` (otherwise, you're essentially trying to create two new instances of `B` instead of just one).  If `convert_param` is a `staticmethod` or a `classmethod`, then you can do the parameter conversion *before* you have an instance (e.g. before `__new__` has been called on the superclass):

```
class B(A):
    @staticmethod
    def convert_param(params):
        # do magic
        return params

    def __new__(cls, params):
        params = cls.convert_params(params)
        return super(B, cls).__new__(cls, params)
```

Additionally, you'll need to change `A`'s `__new__` slightly to not hard-code the type of the instance returned from `object.__new__`:

```
class A(object) : 
    def __new__(cls, param) :
        print('A.__new__ called') 
        x = super(A, cls).__new__(cls)
        x._initialize()    # initialization code
        return x
```

Comment: I edited the code so that it does what you suggested. That was by mistake, but that is not my question. My question is : how to get `return super(B, cls).__new__(cls, params)` work (which is obviously incorrect right now. I can not return an instance class A from the `__new__` method of `class B`)

Comment: @ironstein -- Ahh, I see it now.  You've hard-coded `A` in your call to `object.__new__`.  You need to use `object.__new__(cls)` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Corrected all my misconceptions.